# Calculate average of marks in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I've been struggling with one task I've been doing for learning purposes. I have an object with a few stundents inside and I want to calculate average marks of Steven.

Example:

```
const students = [
{
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'Johnson',
  faculty: 'Faculty of Science',
  modules: [
    {
      title: 'Operating systems',
      marks: [10, 10, 9]
    },
    {
      title: 'Algorythms',
      marks: [8, 10, 8]
    },
    {
      title: 'Statistics',
      marks: [9, 7, 8]
    },
  ]
},
{
  name: 'Steven',
  surname: 'Stevenson',
  faculty: 'Faculty of Science',
  modules: [
    {
      title: 'Operating systems',
      marks: [7, 6, 9]
      },
      {
      title: 'Algorythms',
      marks: [7, 8, 9]
      },  
      {  
      title: 'Statistics',
      marks: [6, 8, 10]
      },
  ]
},
];
```

Using the filter method I was able to filter only Steven from the given object.

```
const studentSteven = students.filter(student => student.name === 'Steven');
```

How can I calculate his average mark of all modules? I would like to achieve this using array methods. Any tip would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const students = [
{
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'Johnson',
  faculty: 'Faculty of Science',
  modules: [
    {
      title: 'Operating systems',
      marks: [10, 10, 9]
    },
    {
      title: 'Algorythms',
      marks: [8, 10, 8]
    },
    {
      title: 'Statistics',
      marks: [9, 7, 8]
    },
  ]
},
{
  name: 'Steven',
  surname: 'Stevenson',
  faculty: 'Faculty of Science',
  modules: [
      {
      title: 'Operating systems',
      marks: [7, 6, 9]
      },
      {
      title: 'Algorythms',
      marks: [7, 8, 9]
      },  
      {  
      title: 'Statistics',
      marks: [6, 8, 10]
      },
  ]
},
];

var studentSteven = students.filter(student => student.name === 'Steven');
studentSteven = studentSteven[0]
let g = 0;
let sum = 0;
for(i = 0;i < studentSteven.modules.length;i++){
sum += studentSteven.modules[i].marks.reduce((s,t)=>{
  g++
  return s + t
})
g++
}
avg = sum/g
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. What is g in your example? Is it equivalent to accumulator in reduce() method?

Comment: ```g``` is just recording the number of total observations.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an array of marks with [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).
2. [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over that array to create an overall average.
3. Return an updated object.

```js
const students=[{name:"John",surname:"Johnson",faculty:"Faculty of Science",modules:[{title:"Operating systems",marks:[10,10,9]},{title:"Algorythms",marks:[8,10,8]},{title:"Statistics",marks:[9,7,8]}]},{name:"Steven",surname:"Stevenson",faculty:"Faculty of Science",modules:[{title:"Operating systems",marks:[7,6,9]},{title:"Algorythms",marks:[7,8,9]},{title:"Statistics",marks:[6,8,10]}]}];

const out = students.map(obj => {

  // Destructure the modules property from the
  // rest of the object properties
  const { modules, ...rest } = obj;

  // Return each marks array, and then flatten them
  const marks = modules.flatMap(obj => obj.marks);

  // `reduce` over the marks array to create a overall
  // sum, divide it by the number of marks,
  // and round up the returned floating-point number
  const average = Math.round(marks.reduce((acc, c) => {
    return acc + c;
  }, 0) / marks.length);

  // Return a new updated object
  return { ...rest, average, modules };

});

console.log(out);
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the students array and for every student again `map` over the modules array and add a property called `averageMarks` to the each module object.

```js
const students = [
  {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Johnson",
    faculty: "Faculty of Science",
    modules: [
      { title: "Operating systems", marks: [10, 10, 9] },
      { title: "Algorythms", marks: [8, 10, 8] },
      { title: "Statistics", marks: [9, 7, 8] },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Steven",
    surname: "Stevenson",
    faculty: "Faculty of Science",
    modules: [
      { title: "Operating systems", marks: [7, 6, 9] },
      { title: "Algorythms", marks: [7, 8, 9] },
      { title: "Statistics", marks: [6, 8, 10] },
    ],
  },
];

const updatedStudents = students.map((st) => ({
  ...st,
  modules: st.modules.map((mod) => ({
    ...mod,
    averageMarks: mod.marks.reduce((sum, m) => sum + m) / mod.marks.length,
  })),
}));

console.log(updatedStudents);
```

If you also need to calculate the average of all modules, then you can chain the above result with another `map` and add an `average` property for each student.

```js
const students = [
  {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Johnson",
    faculty: "Faculty of Science",
    modules: [
      { title: "Operating systems", marks: [10, 10, 9] },
      { title: "Algorythms", marks: [8, 10, 8] },
      { title: "Statistics", marks: [9, 7, 8] },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Steven",
    surname: "Stevenson",
    faculty: "Faculty of Science",
    modules: [
      { title: "Operating systems", marks: [7, 6, 9] },
      { title: "Algorythms", marks: [7, 8, 9] },
      { title: "Statistics", marks: [6, 8, 10] },
    ],
  },
];

const updatedStudents = students
  .map((st) => ({
    ...st,
    modules: st.modules.map((mod) => ({
      ...mod,
      averageMarks: mod.marks.reduce((sum, m) => sum + m) / mod.marks.length,
    })),
  }))
  .map((st) => ({
    ...st,
    average:
      st.modules.reduce((sum, { averageMarks }) => sum + averageMarks, 0) /
      st.modules.length,
  }));

console.log(updatedStudents);
```